# django:How to get the response location(url) of HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: django, redirect

I am using django to dev a website. I need to get the url (location) from the redirect response, but can't find any method or attr.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 223, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "/opt/dbinabox/DBInBoxWeb/dbinabox/dbasrm/altus.py", line 16, in process_response
    print response.header
AttributeError: 'HttpResponseRedirect' object has no attribute 'header'
```

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: Unit Testing maybe?  Why do you care? @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `response.url`. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect.url):

> This read-only attribute represents the URL the response will redirect to (equivalent to the Location response header).